Best process to ensure only (self-)signed artifacts are deployed to Azure
It seems it's not possible to configure Azure resources like App Services and Azure Functions to only run code that has been (self-)signed by us (i.e. whitelisting). So we somehow have to do the signature check during our deployment phase. We are using Azure DevOps Services.
We could add a custom task in our pipeline that does the signature validation check. But then the check would be a task inside our YAML files, which are typically controlled by teams themselves. We would like this check to happen outside of the control of the pipeline creator.
What would be the best way to realize this? We did some research and we think a DevOps pipeline check, as defined in this article, would maybe be a good solution. We could add such a check to our Service Connections, which would call a custom Azure Function or REST API that validates the signature of a deployment artifact.
Does this seem like a good solution? Does Azure or Azure DevOps Services offer a better solution?

If you just need to take a simply check operation for the data from the response of the invoked function or REST API, using the Invoke Azure function or Invoke REST API task as a check is a good way. However, if you need to parse more complex data from the response and take more complex operations using the data, the two tasks might be not available.
If you have developed a custom pipeline task that can take more complex operations, you can consider adding this task as a step of pipeline decorator.
Pipeline decorator is a type of Azure DevOps extension which can let you add steps to the beginning and end of every job. Once you installed a custom decorator into your Azure DevOps organization, by default, the steps set in the decorator will be automatically added into all the running jobs within the organization.
When the pipeline creators set up a pipeline, they just need to add the steps they want, and then when running the pipeline, the decorator steps will be automatically run before or after the steps added by creators in each job.
Related documentations as reference:

Author a pipeline decorator
Pipeline decorator expression context


